# Issue with the sort command in open stack server list in an ubuntu environment

Tags: shell, sorting, ubuntu, openstack

I am trying to sort the output here as per compute systems:

[image]

I tried with `openstack server list --all --long -c ID -c Name -c Status -c Host | sort -k4` but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me how to can I sort this as per Host name? where 460001 number is in ascending order under Host column.

PS: the below is sample and is not an actual output from any anywhere.

Regards,
Tayto

Answer (score 1):

Just append  **`--sort-column Host`** to your `openstack command`. But you should make sure that the **`Host`** column can't have `None` or `null` value.

Check from `openstack server list -h`:

```
output formatters:
  output formatter options

  -f {csv,json,table,value,yaml}, --format {csv,json,table,value,yaml}
                        the output format, defaults to table
  -c COLUMN, --column COLUMN
                        specify the column(s) to include, can be repeated to
                        show multiple columns
  --sort-column SORT_COLUMN
                        specify the column(s) to sort the data (columns
                        specified first have a priority, non-existing columns
                        are ignored), can be repeated
```

Or if you don't have `--sort-column` option, you should `sort -k8` but not **`-k4`**.

Or use `openstack server list --all --long -c ID -c Name -c Status -c Host -f value | sort -k4` just with **`-f value`**, but it will separate the columns by blank space.

Comment: This is what I have:                                                                                                           
  `output formatters:
  output formatter options

  -f {csv,json,table,value,yaml}, --format {csv,json,table,value,yaml}
                        the output format, defaults to table
  -c COLUMN, --column COLUMN
                        specify the column(s) to include, can be repeated`

Comment: @Tayto what's your `openstack` version? could you use `--sort-column` option? and what's your `python-openstackclient` version? I use `python-openstackclient==5.2.0`.

Comment: apologies for the late response. The version is:                                                            `[root@server ~(admin)]# nova-manage --version
16.1.8
`

Comment: what about the result of `pip freeze|grep openstackclient`?

Comment: `[root@server ~(admin)]# pip freeze | grep openstack
django-openstack-auth==3.6.1
openstacksdk==0.9.18
python-openstackclient==3.12.2`

Comment: Maybe the **Pike** version or the `python-openstackclient` need to upgrade. Just try to update `python-openstackclient` to the newest `pip install python-openstackclient -U`, if it can't work, you should update the `openstack`'s version.

Comment: I was hoping to use the sort command without updating the version. Just using linux commands only.

Comment: what about `sort -k8`?

Comment: It worked :) Do you have a link which explains this "k8" property of sort in detail?

Comment: @Tayto just `man sort`, `-k, --key=KEYDEF sort via a key;`. And the **KEYDEF**: `KEYDEF is ..., characters in a field are counted from the beginning of the preceding whitespace. ...`

Comment: Yes, however with this command `openstack server list --all --long -c ID -c Name -c Status -c Host | sort -k8`, I can see that it is sorting on the basis of host column only? Also in host column we have, for example, server460001. So, its counting till 6 and sorting the rest?

Comment: Get your hands dirty.

Comment: sorts sees this(comma separated in the example):
|,id,|,name,|,status,|,host,| ... figured it out :) Thanks.